# why afxwin.h and afxmt.h cause VC++2008 Form App crash?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++

I am creating a **VC++2008 Windows Form Application** which needs some classes from our old **VC6 project**.

Then I have to add **afxwin.h** and **afxmt.h** into the **stdafx.h** to get compile fine. But when I run it, it crash with this information:

[image]

In order to find the cause, I removed all files from old project and just leave files created by IDE (professional version). It is still the same. Then I commented out these **#include** of **afxwin.h** and **afxmt.h** in the **stdafx.h** file, it worked fine (still no old files). If put back those **#include** it will crash again.

My project configruation is like this:
[image]

If I change **Common Language Runtime Support** to **No Common Language Runtime Support**. The code generated by IDE cannot be compiled. Other options are not good as well.

There must be a way to avoid the crash. Anybody can help me?

**EDIT:**

in the error dialog window, there is a line: **File: f:\dd\vctools\crt_dbd\self_x86\crt\src\dbgheap.c** But I don't have **f** drive on my machine. why??

**EDIT 2:**

it worked if I run **Release**. why??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MFC is not getting initialized properly in this scenario.  Right-click your Winforms project, Properties, Linker, Input.  Set the "Force Symbol References" setting to `__DllMainCRTStartup@12`.

Connect feedback article [is here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/99715/using-mfc-in-winform-application-generate-heap-error-crtisvalidheappointer).

Comment: Your solution works (thanks!), however the referenced Connect article seems to be gone. Do you know of any other resource that provides a bit more in-depth information?

Comment: Microsoft deleted a large number of old feedback items shortly before VS2012 and Windows 8 were released.  Not much I can do about that, use Google to search for background info first, ask a question about it next.